# Cannot convert value of Unsafe pointer<Int8>? to expected argument type xcode 8

Tags: ios, swift3

With Xcode8, I've been upgrading to Swift 3. However I'm getting this error:

> Cannot convert value of Unsafe pointer? to expected argument type 'String'

With this line of code:

```
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: (name as NSString).utf8String, attributes: [])
```

What does this mean and how do I resolve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DispatchQueue(label:)` takes a regular Swift string, so you can simply use `name`. Also, the `attributes` parameter has a default value of `[]`, so you can simply write

```
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: name)
```

Comment: @TomV Happy to help! You should accept this answer if it solved your problem.